# Inequality with Binomial distribution

Tags: probability, inequality

Let $n$ and $1\leq k \leq n$ be natural numbers. Prove the inequality
    $$\sum_{i=k}^n \binom{n}{i}\bigg(\frac{k}{n+1}\bigg)^i\bigg(1-\frac{k}{n+1}\bigg)^{n-i} \leq 1 - \frac{1}{e} $$

Equivalently, if $X\sim$ Bin($n$,$\frac{k}{n+1}$), prove that $\mathbb{P}[X\geq k] \leq 1 - \frac{1}{e}$.

My attempt: It may be helpful to show that the LHS tends to $1-\frac{1}{e}$ as $n \to \infty$ (already did that) and that the LHS is an increasing function on $n$ (have not done that).

Comment: I don't think @gimusi's argument is correct.

Comment: did you verify after my new comments?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Note that

$$\sum_{i=k}^n \binom{n}{i}\bigg(\frac{k}{n+1}\bigg)^i\bigg(1-\frac{k}{n+1}\bigg)^{n-i}
=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\bigg(\frac{k}{n+1}\bigg)^i\bigg(1-\frac{k}{n+1}\bigg)^{n-i}
-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{n}{i}\bigg(\frac{k}{n+1}\bigg)^i\bigg(1-\frac{k}{n+1}\bigg)^{n-i}=1^n-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{n}{i}\bigg(\frac{k}{n+1}\bigg)^i\bigg(1-\frac{k}{n+1}\bigg)^{n-i}$$

and show that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{n}{i}\bigg(\frac{k}{n+1}\bigg)^i\bigg(1-\frac{k}{n+1}\bigg)^{n-i}\stackrel{k=1}\ge \sum_{i=0}^0 \binom{n}{i}\bigg(\frac{1}{n+1}\bigg)^i\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\bigg)^{n-i}=\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\bigg)^{n}\ge\frac 1e$$

Comment: Sorry, but how did you get from $sum_{i=0}^1$ (things) to n/(n+1)*(1-1/(n+1))^{n-1}; i.e. how did k dissapear magically and became 1?

Comment: @DesmondMiles sorry there is a typo k ia assumed $=1$, I check and fix this point

Comment: @DesmondMiles  I've made also a stupid mistake with the sum index. Now it should be ok and also simpler!

Comment: Thank you but how exactly do we show the inequality with (k=1) written above it? Apologies if I am not seeing something stupid. The gap in my attempt is quite similar.

Comment: @DesmondMiles Because it is a sum of positive terms thus the minimum is attained fro k=1, and the quantity obtained is bounded below by $1/e$.

Comment: But the terms in the sum depend on k, what if the sum is in overall bigger for some special k>1? I am quite certain there should a counterexample in general.

Comment: @DesmondMiles The sum is$ \ge$ of is first term (that is for$ k=1$) and the first term is$ \ge 1/e$ thus the sum is $\ge 1/e$. What is your doubt?

Comment: The first term is for i = 0, i.e. equals (1 - k/(n+1))^n which unfortunately converges to e^(-k)

Comment: @DesmondMiles For k=1 I think that the claim is clear. Note that for k=2 the sum ha 2 terms and it can be shown that it is $\ge \frac{3}{e^2}\ge \frac 1 e$.

Comment: @DesmondMiles Anyway we don't need to consider all the cases since, fixed n, the sum is minimum for k=1 and it is equal to $\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\bigg)^{n}$ which is $\ge\frac 1e$ thus the sum is bigger than $\frac 1 e$.

Comment: @DesmondMiles Indeed for the case $k=2$ we have $$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{n}{i}\bigg(\frac{k}{n+1}\bigg)^i\bigg(1-\frac{k}{n+1}\bigg)^{n-i}\stackrel{k=2}\ge \sum_{i=0}^1 \binom{n}{i}\bigg(\frac{1}{n+1}\bigg)^i\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\bigg)^{n-i}
=\bigg(1-\frac{2}{n+1}\bigg)^{n}+n\bigg(\frac{2}{n+1}\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac{2}{n+1}\bigg)^{n-1}=...$$

Comment: @DesmondMiles $$...=\bigg(1-\frac{2}{n+1}\bigg)^{n-1} \left(\bigg(1-\frac{2}{n+1}\bigg)+\frac{2n}{n+1}\right)
=\bigg(1-\frac{2}{n+1}\bigg)^{n-1}\frac{3n-1}{n+1}           
=\bigg(1-\frac{2}{n+1}\bigg)^{n+1}\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)^2\frac{3n-1}{n+1}
=\bigg(1-\frac{2}{n+1}\bigg)^{n+1}\frac{(3n-1)(n+1)}{(n-1)^2}          
\ge\frac 3 {e^2}$$

Comment: gimusi, sorry, but I am not convinced that $sum_{i=0}^{k-1} f(k,i)$ for $f > 0$ is generally minimized at $k=1$. Indeed, $f(1,0)$ (which is for $k=1$) may not be less than $f(2,0) + f(2,1)$ (which is for $k=2$), e.g. if $f = \frac{1}{i+5*k}$  (then $f(1,0) = 1$ and $f(2,0) + f(2,1) = 1/2 + 1/7 < 1$. So one should really show how the particular form of our sum is minimized at $k=1$.